# root access for php exec function

Tags: php, exec, root, sudo

I am trying to write a php program which can execute **service fcserver status** to find whether my chat room is running or not. If it  is running then output should be

[image: http://i40.tinypic.com/15ysobn.png]

and if it's not running then the output should be

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/2mo5t3a.png]

If it is not running then there should be an start button to start the chat room. and when somebody clicks on that button, my script executes **service fcserver start** command.

well, i can't execute commands like "service fcserver status" or "service fcserver start" as www-data user. I need a root permission. please help me!! what are the ways to get this little task done without compromising with server security?

Thank you!

Comment: RTLM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

Comment: is this a 123flashchat by any chance? and why would u want an end user to start chat rooms for you?

Comment: This has been asked many time. Search SO for: `php exec root` and you'll find plenty of info (and most of it will tell you that it's not a wise approach due to security concerns).

Answer (score 0):

This is purely in response to the status portion of the question:

How frequently do you need to poll this?  On demand?  Or would regular polling work (i.e., a cron job)?

If a cron job works, you could have a root level cron job produce a status file in the web directory every 1-5 minutes.  Then php is not executing the system command itself, but rather just reading a status file and parsing.

With this, you would at least be able to see up to the minute status info, without compromising any security.

As for executing a system command from a remote web interface, it would be highly discourage to do so.